# Dropdown list blur event

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, focus, blur

I am building a dropdown list of anchor tags (not a select):

```
<ul>
  <li class="selected"><a href="#">List item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">List item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">List item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">List item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

When a user selected the list, it triggers a *focus* state which shows all items.
I also want it to *blur* when the user clicks off of the ul or selects an item.

Is this possible?

> **Note:** `.blur()` and `.focus()` only work with form elements.

Comment: onblur and onfocus are triggered also by other elements, just set [`tabindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.tabIndex) for the `ul`.

Comment: What do you mean by `When a user selected the list`

Comment: Sorry. What I mean was, using a mouse, the user clicks the first item and the others are revealed.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) event

```
$( "ul" ).mouseleave(function() {
     //console.log('similar to blur');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just .toggle() for my dropdown

```
function DropDownMenu() {
  var item1 = document.getElementById("dropdownmenu1");
     $("#dropdownmenu1").toggle();
 }
```

, this is when I click on the dropdown. If I click elsewhere on the page, I have this;

```
function BlurDropDown() {
    $("#dropdownmenu1").fadeOut(1000);
}
```

And on my div for the rest of the page, I have set a onmousedown event

```
    <div id="page" onmousedown="BlurDropDown()">
```

My menu is placed on the master page.